# Route parameter disappears while acessing a route

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have routes:

```
routes: {
   "": "main",
   "!/order/:id": "order",
   "!/order": "order"
},
```

Then I access for example to `http://mysite.ru/#!/order/21`. But my URL changes to: `http://mysite.ru/#!/order/`

The number 21 is hiding. How to save this number in my URL?

Comment: THere's no magic in Backbone router. I anything calling `navigate()` in the call stack?

Comment: For example, i access to url mysite.ru/#!/order/21 and have success, but my url becomes mysite.ru/#!/order And after reloading i have fail, because id is not defined. Users can'not copy the direct url to my order (mysite.ru/#!/order/21), because they see only mysite.ru/#!/order without id number.

Comment: Becomes? By magic?

Comment: I don't know) I create project to show my problem:  
https://jsfiddle.net/alego/ohayr3aa  If you click "Order 1" and then click "refresh page" content with current ID will be empty

Comment: yeah, look at lines 59 and 62

Answer (score 3):

I think it is cascading. Try to set the general order routing first:

```
routes: {
   "": "main",       
   "!/order": "order",
   "!/order/:id": "order"
},
```

Comment: Thanks, but my routing is work too. My problem is crashing url after reloading page.

Comment: For example, i access to url http://mysite.ru/#!/order/21 and have success, but my url becomes http://mysite.ru/#!/order/ And after reloading i have fail, because id is not defined. Users can'not copy the direct url to my order (http://mysite.ru/#!/order/21), because they see only http://mysite.ru/#!/order/ without id number.

Comment: You should not be re-routed from mysite.ru/#!/order/21 to mysite.ru/#!/order unless you want this. Do you want the customer to see the ID? 
Otherwise it might be smart to save the ID in a global variable in stead of in the url.

Comment: After the the user browsed to: myssite.ru/#!/order/21 what does your script do? It looks like you are redirected. 
Maybe with a router.navigate() ?

Comment: Thanks for comments. I create project to show my problem:

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/alego/ohayr3aa/
If you click "Order 1" and then click "refresh page" content with current ID will be empty

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your router by making the `:id` parameter optional, since your callback is the same for both order routes.

```
routes: {
   "": "main",       
   "!/order(/:id)": "order",
},
```